# update nested schema express

Tags: rest, express, mongoose, put

I have a problem when I want to update my nested objects in express. Here is my code:

```
.put(function(req, res) {
            Place.findById(req.params.place_id, function(err, place) {

                    if (err)
                            res.send(err);
                    if (typeof req.body.zip !== 'undefined') {
                            place.zip = req.body.zip;     
                    }
                    if (typeof req.body.loc !== 'undefined') {
                            place.loc = req.body.loc;
                    }
                    if (typeof req.body.coordinates !== 'undefined') {
                            place.coordinates = req.body.coordinates;
                    }

                    place.save(function(err) {
                            if (err)
                                    res.send(err);

                            res.json({ message: 'Place updated!' });
                    });

            });

    });
```

It is working, when I want to update the zip, but I cannot modify the coordinates. I tried also the place.loc.coordinates. I am using curl to update, maybe that command the wrong one. I tried the

```
curl -X PUT -d loc.coordinates=[1.3,3.2] 'http://localhost:8080/api/places/A38'
curl -X PUT -d coordinates=[1.3,3.2] 'http://localhost:8080/api/places/A38'
```

commands too.

And my schema is:

```
var placeSchema = new Schema({
   _id:  String,
  zip: Number,
    loc: {
      type: { type: String }
    , coordinates: []
  }
```

});

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried both of your ideas, but unfortunately those are not worked. 
I found a solution, maybe it is not elegant, but works:
I changed my schema to:

```
var placeSchema = new Schema({
  _id:  String,
  zip: Number,
  loc: {
    type: Object
  ,   index: '2dsphere'
  }
});
```

And my new code is:

```
if (typeof req.body.coordinates !== 'undefined') {
                            place.loc = { type: 'Point', coordinates: req.body.coordinates };
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Mongoose what the `coordinates` array contains if you want it to track changes for you.  So change you schema definition to:

```js
var placeSchema = new Schema({
   _id:  String,
  zip: Number,
  loc: {
    type: { type: String },
    coordinates: [Number]
  }
});
```

The alternative would be to explicitly mark `coordinates` as changed:

```js
place.coordinates = req.body.coordinates;
place.markModified('coordinates');
```